# get new inserted ID in MVC Controller to jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

I am updating an entity normally inside a controller as follows :-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Project project)
{
  //var model = new CompositeImageModel(0);
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //var model = new CompositeImageModel(project.ProjectID);
    db.Projects.Add(project);
    db.SaveChanges();
    ViewBag.ProjectID = project.ProjectID;

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return View();
}
```

And I wish to grab this new id "ViewBag.ProjectID" inside my Jquery AJAX code :-

```
onSaveBegin: function () {
  //CODE FOR SAVE BEGIN    
  $('#imageList').fadeIn('slow');
  $("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/222"); }); 

},
```

instead of the hardcoded "222".

How can I get it?

Thanks for your help and time

***************UPDATE***************************************************
So I have updated my Jquery as follows :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var imageList = $('#imageList'),
        submitButt = $('#submitButt');

    //hide the imageList initially
    imageList.hide(); //hide all but the first paragraph

    });


    var Project = {
        save: function () {
            var projectForm = $("#projectForm");
            if (projectForm.valid()) {
                projectForm.submit();
            }
            else {
                Project.onInvalidForm();
            }
        },
        onInvalidForm: function () {
            //CODE FOR INVALID FORM 
        },
        onSaveBegin: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE BEGIN    
            $('#imageList').fadeIn('slow');
        },
        onSaveSuccess: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE SUCCESS    
        },
        onSaveFailure: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE FAILURE    
            alert(ViewBag.ProjectID);
        },
        onSaveComplete: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE COMPLETE    
            //var hfProjectId = $("#hfProjectId").val();
            //$("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/" + hfProjectId); });
            $("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/"+@(ViewBag.ProjectID) ); }); 
        }
    };
```

I have moved the code to onSaveComplete, since I should have the ProjectID then, but still am not able to get it yet.
however both options will not work.

***************UPDATE 2* *********************************************

```
@model MvcCommons.Models.Project

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
```

}

```
<h2>Create</h2>

@{    
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";    
Html.EnableClientValidation();    
Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();
```

}

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

    var imageList = $('#imageList'),
        submitButt = $('#submitButt');

        //hide the imageList initially
    imageList.hide(); //hide all but the first paragraph

    });


    var Project = {
        save: function () {
            var projectForm = $("#projectForm");
            if (projectForm.valid()) {
                projectForm.submit();
            }
            else {
                Project.onInvalidForm();
            }
        },
        onInvalidForm: function () {
            //CODE FOR INVALID FORM 
        },
        onSaveBegin: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE BEGIN    
            $('#imageList').fadeIn('slow');
        },
        onSaveSuccess: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE SUCCESS    
        },
        onSaveFailure: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE FAILURE    
            alert(ViewBag.ProjectID);
        },
        onSaveComplete: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE COMPLETE    
            //var hfProjectId = $("#hfProjectId").val();
            //$("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/" + hfProjectId); });

            $("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/"+@(ViewBag.ProjectID) ); }); 
        }
    };
```

@{
    var projectID = int.Parse(ViewBag.ProjectID);
 }

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "/Create",
    new { },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "projectFormContainer",
        OnComplete = "Project.onSaveComplete",
        OnFailure = "Project.onSaveFailure",
        OnSuccess = "Project.onSaveSuccess",
        OnBegin = "Project.onSaveBegin"
    },
    new { id = "projectForm", name = "projectForm" }))
    {

```
         @Html.Hidden("hfProjectId", ViewBag.ProjectID)

        <div class="editor-label">          
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectTitle)       
         </div>       
         <div class="editor-field">          
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectTitle)          
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectTitle)       
         </div>       
         <div class="editor-label">          
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectText)       
         </div>       
         <div class="editor-field">          
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectText)          
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectText)       
         </div>       
         <p>       
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Project.save();" />       
         </p>    
      </div>    
}


<div id='imageList'>
    <h2>Upload Image(s)</h2>
    @{ 
        Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/File/ImageUpload.cshtml", new MvcCommons.ViewModels.ImageModel((int)ViewBag.ProjectID));
     }
</div>
```

@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

Code updated with latest changes

******************UPDATED**********************************************

Mode updates :-
Change the @Html.Hidden to this now :-

```
            @if(Model != null)
        {
             @Html.Hidden("hfProjectId", Model.ProjectID)
        }
```

The Javascript is still the same :=

```
            onSaveComplete: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE COMPLETE    
            var hfProjectId = $("#hfProjectId").val();
            alert(hfProjectId);
            $("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/" + hfProjectId); });
            //$("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/"+@(ViewBag.ProjectID) ); }); 
        }
```

change the var projectID

```
@{
if (Model != null)  
{
    var projectID = Model.ProjectID;
}
```

}

in the controller, returning a "View", with the model

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Project project)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.ProjectID = project.ProjectID;
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            return View("Create", project);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Still no luck though!

**************** FINAL UPDATE **************************************************
I have decided to create a Project View Model and try to pass variables through it, since the ViewBag was not working in my case.  So I changed the HttpPost Create function in the Controller to look as follows :-

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Project project)
    {
        ProjectModel viewModel = new ProjectModel();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            viewModel.Project = project;
            return View("Index", viewModel);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

However this still did not refresh the ProjectID, and so I have decided to abandon this for the time being and try to come up with a better design.  However if you could see soemthign wrong that I am doing please comment on this.

This is my final Create View :-

```
@model MvcCommons.ViewModels.ProjectModel
@{
var projectID = Model.Project.ProjectID;
```

}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

### Create

```
@{    
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";    
Html.EnableClientValidation();    
Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();
```

}

`

`    
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
    var imageList = $('#imageList'),
        submitButt = $('#submitButt');

    //hide the imageList initially
    imageList.hide(); //hide all but the first paragraph

    });

    var Project = {
        save: function () {
            var projectForm = $("#projectForm");
            if (projectForm.valid()) {
                projectForm.submit();
            }
            else {
                Project.onInvalidForm();
            }
        },
        onInvalidForm: function () {
            //CODE FOR INVALID FORM 
        },
        onSaveBegin: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE BEGIN    
            alert('onSaveBegin ' + @(projectID));
            $('#imageList').fadeIn('slow');
        },
        onSaveSuccess: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE SUCCESS    
            //alert('onSaveSuccess')
        },
        onSaveFailure: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE FAILURE    
            //alert('onSaveFailure ' + @(projectID));
        },
        onSaveComplete: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE COMPLETE    
            //alert('onSaveComplete ' + @(projectID))
            //$("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/"+@(projectID)); });
            $("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/" + hfProjectId); });
        }
    };
```

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(    
"/Create",    
new { },    
new AjaxOptions    
{       
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,       
    UpdateTargetId = "projectFormContainer",       
    OnComplete = "Project.onSaveComplete",       
    OnFailure = "Project.onSaveFailure",
    OnSuccess = "Project.onSaveSuccess",
    OnBegin = "Project.onSaveBegin"    
},    
new { id = "projectForm", name = "projectForm" }))    
{    
    <div>       

        @*@Html.Hidden("hfProjectId", projectID)*@ 
        @Html.Hidden("hfProjectId", Model.Project.ProjectID) 

        <div class="editor-label">          
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Project.ProjectTitle)       
         </div>       
         <div class="editor-field">          
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Project.ProjectTitle)          
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Project.ProjectTitle)       
         </div>       
         <div class="editor-label">          
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Project.ProjectText)       
         </div>       
         <div class="editor-field">          
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Project.ProjectText)          
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Project.ProjectText)       
         </div>       
         <p>
```

@*               *@

}

```
<div id='imageList'>
    <h2>Upload Image(s)</h2>
    @{ 
        //Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/File/ImageUpload.cshtml", new MvcCommons.ViewModels.ImageModel((int)ViewBag.ProjectID));
        Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/File/ImageUpload.cshtml", new MvcCommons.ViewModels.ImageModel(projectID));
     }
</div>
```

@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

Comment: Assuming razor syntax, replace 222 with `ViewBag.ProjectID`.

Comment: Phone apparently missed the @, but make sure to add the @ prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy way** (Not very sure about it)

```
$("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/"+@(ViewBag.ProjectID) ); });
```

**The Normal way**

1- Put a HiddenField inside your view

2- Get the value from `ViewBag.ProjectID`  and assign it to this hidden field

3- Read it with jQuery and then use it wherever you want.

an Example should eb added to this answer right away.

**Example:**

**Update**

```
//  Get the projectID value
    var projectID = int.parse(ViewBag.ProjectID);

// add a hiddenfield and set it's value to the projectID
@Html.Hidden("hfProjectId", projectID)

// inside your jQuery code, get the hiddenField value
var hfProjectId = $("#hfProjectId").val();

// use this value inside your code
$("#imageList").click(function () { $("#imageList").load("/File/ImageUpload/"+hfProjectId ); });
```

Comment: hi Mohammed thanks for your reply. The "Easy way" does not seem to work, and the second option, I am geting an error on the @Html.Hidden saying "'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MvcCommons.Models.Project>' has no applicable method named 'Hidden' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax."

Comment: updated the question, changed a bit the code around but still getting problems

Comment: ok, I get it, kindly check my modified solution within a minute

Comment: Hi Mohammed, does the var projectID = int.parse(ViewBag.ProjectID); goes into the view? If yes where?  Can't figure out where to place that

Comment: the problem was that the type of anything under `ViewBag` is Dynamic, and extension methods like `Hidden` cannot accept `Dynamic` variables as parameters.
the so-simple solution was to get the value into a new variable, and then provide this new variable to the `Hidden` method

Comment: I tried this @{
    var projectID = int.Parse(ViewBag.ProjectID);    
 }
but still getting an error on the HTML.Hidden

Comment: @Johann: at the very beginning of your view, just under the part that defines the model type of your view.
ex: `@model Project`

Comment: no luck :(     @model MvcCommons.Models.Project
@{
    var projectID = int.Parse(ViewBag.ProjectID); 
}

Comment: still fighting with this, can't get the ProjectID in my Jquery